# MS-Access - you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified aggregate function, Any other solution?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

```
 SQL = "TRANSFORM FIRST(a.TimeStamp1) "
 SQL = SQL & "SELECT a.DealName, DealList.SettlementDate "
 SQL = SQL & "FROM DealList, DealStepLog a INNER JOIN DealStepMasterData b on b.StepName = a.DealStep "
 SQL = SQL & "WHERE b.StepClassification = 'Compliance' "
 SQL = SQL & "GROUP BY DealName "
 SQL = SQL & "PIVOT dealStep "
```

I know I have to put 'SettlementDate' in GROUP BY section but I dont want to group by settlementDate, any other options??

Comment: Got It, By updating the above code

Answer (score 1):

Then you will have to use one of the *aggregating functions*, for example one of these:

```
First(SettlementDate)
Last(SettlementDate)
Max(SettlementDate)
Avg(SettlementDate)
Min(SettlementDate)
```